# How can I recode a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the received a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{('M6.9', 'M31.467', 'M3.733'): '2',
('M15.304', 'M12.063', 'M30.138', 'M20.463', 'M20.463'): '2', 
('M29', 'M23.59'): '2'}
```

I have created a second dictionary to decode it like so:

```
{('M6.9', 'M31.467', 'M3.733'): 'bedrooms',
('M15.304', 'M12.063', 'M30.138', 'M20.463', 'M20.463'): 'toilets', 
('M29', 'M23.59'): 'occupants'}
```

How can I recode my first dictionary with my second dictionary, so that I get as output a dictionary that looks like this?

```
{'bedrooms': '2',
'toilets': '2', 
'occupants': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which iterates over the keys of the dictionaries, since they are the same:

```py
def recodeDict(dict_names, dict_numbers):
    new_dict = {}
    for key in dict_names:
        new_dict[dict_names[key]] = dict_numbers[key]
    return new_dict
```

You can also do it this way:

```py
new_dict = {dict_names[key]: dict_numbers[key] for key in dict_names}
```

EDIT:

Combining that with Sagi's answer:

```
c = { v: a[k] for k,v in b.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
a = {('M6.9', 'M31.467', 'M3.733'): '2',
('M15.304', 'M12.063', 'M30.138', 'M20.463', 'M20.463'): '2', 
('M29', 'M23.59'): '2'}

b = {('M6.9', 'M31.467', 'M3.733'): 'bedrooms',
('M15.304', 'M12.063', 'M30.138', 'M20.463', 'M20.463'): 'toilets', 
('M29', 'M23.59'): 'occupants'}

c = {}

for k,v in b.items():
    c[v] = a[k]

print(c)
```

> {'bedrooms': '2', 'toilets': '2', 'occupants': '2'}